# i get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" when i run my .html and .js file

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

i'm new in react.js, i used CDN links to compile some simple react.js code into my html, but i get this error:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

then i searched and i saw somebody said that i should add:

```
type="text/babel" or type="text/jsx"
```

to my script tag, i did, but after that, my html didn't know my .js file!

this is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head lang="fa">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <title> title </title>
</head>

<body> 

  <div id="app"> </div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"</script>

  <script type="text/babel" src="myreact.js"> </script>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is my react.js file:

```
'use strict';

class MyComponent extends React.Component{ 
    render()
    {
      return  "hello";
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent/> , document.getElementById('app')
);
```

please help me to code in react.js.

Comment: Please check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407632/how-to-render-a-react-component-using-reactdom-render

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to render a react component using ReactDOM Render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407632/how-to-render-a-react-component-using-reactdom-render)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using CDN, first two you need are to render React into a DOM and the third one (babel) enables JSX and ES6. I have reordered the imports, have included cdn for babel after importing react and react-dom.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/babel">
    'use strict'
    class Application extends React.Component {
     render() {
      return(
          <div>React App</div>
      );
     }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, it works when i put my react.js code in my html file with <script> tag, but i want to have separate .js file and make a link to this .js file from my html. can i do this? do you have any idea?

Comment: Yes, you can, what is your directory structure? Where is your js located?

Comment: my .js file and my .html file are in the same folder.  react\file.html and react\file.js. what should i do?

Comment: Change this `<script type="text/babel" src="myreact.js"> </script>` to `<script type="text/babel" src="./myreact.js"> </script>`

Comment: And if my answer was helpful, please accept it :) Thanks in advance :)